# Read Title of the web page in web browser control

Tags: windows-mobile, c#-2.0

I am very new to C#, I am trying to do some web service request to my server. This app is for windows mobile 6.

I have used web browser to load a page from the server. I need to know the Title of the page which has been returned.

I googled and found found solutions like try using HTMLDocument, webbrowser1.DocumentText etc. But none of them worked.

I request help from the experts here, how I can over come this problem?

Some solutions which came to my mind are:

1. Download the file using some way and store it in a temp directory and load the web browser with the local URL.
   ==> Any API's for doing this is available?
2. is there a possibility of using xmlhttprequest methods to get the info?
   ==> if so how? any sample of using this method in C#?

Any kind of information, links, samples etc., would be of great help.

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
Vinay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some extensive search and could not find the solution.

As an alternative, I did a HttpWebRequest and saved the file locally after parsing the Title and loaded the same to webBrowser object.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `Document Completed` event and you can get the title below is the code for the same:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = webBrowser1.DocumentTitle;
}
```